# Android Studio shows no Javadoc for Realm classes

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, javadoc, realm

I am experimenting with Realm for an Android project, unfortunately Android Studio does not show the Javadoc for the Realm classes.

I did some searching on this topic, and found some discussions indicating that the problem was fixed in Android Studio 1.4 (I am using 1.5.1).  These discussions imply that this is an issue with Android-Studio/Gradle/Maven.  I am a novice with respect to Gradle and Maven.

Things I've tried (based on advice in the discussions I found):

1. Added to app's build.gradle

   ```
   apply plugin: 'idea'
   idea {
       module {
           downloadJavadoc = true
           downloadSources = true
       }
   }
   ```
2. File->Other Settings->Default Settings->Maven->Importing

   ```
   check boxes for 'Sources' and 'Documentation'
   ```

After making the above changes, I did "Invalidate Caches/Restart...", but there was no change in the behavior.

Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: I'm still seeing this with Realm 3.5.0 (and the older version 3.3.1) in Android Studio 2.3 -- I get no JavaDoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in our recent releases which has meant that the sources/javadoc wasn't released as part of the library. We are working on fixing it. You can follow progress here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1971

Comment: Note, it should be fixed for our SNAPSHOT release now.

Comment: It looks like this problem may have come back. See my comment above.